# Запятая перед "хоть"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, составные-союзы

Почему в этом предложении перед "хоть" не ставится запятая? На РешуЕГЭ в пояснении речь о каких-то однородных членах, но я не очень понимаю, о каких именно.

**Пойдёшь с рюкзаком за город и, если ничего живого за день не усмотрел, возвращаешься(,) хоть и довольный ходьбой, но всё-⁠таки с ощущением, что чего-то важного не было.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Пойдёшь** с рюкзаком за город **и**, если ничего живого за день не усмотрел, возвращаешься **хоть и довольный** ходьбой, **но** всё-⁠таки **с ощущением,** что чего-то важного не было.*

Это тема "однородные  определения как дуплексивы", то есть члены предложения **с двойной связью.**

Они связаны с грамматическим подлежащим  и со сказуемым:  *(ты) пойдешь и возвращаешься (какой?) **хоть и довольный, но с ощущением.***

Здесь **два определения**, согласованное и несогласованное. Главное предложение **определенно-личное**.

**[Розенталь, пункт 2(3)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)**

2. **Не обособляются** распространенные определения: 3) связанные по смыслу не только с подлежащим, но и со сказуемым, **в состав которого они входят**: Вечером Екатерина Дмитриевна **прибежала** из Юридического клуба **взволнованная и радостная** (А. Т.) — в роли определительного оборота два одиночных определения.